# How to overcome the re-render the child component in Next.js with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, next.js13

**I need to address the issue of unnecessary re-rendering of child components' pages, but we must halt this re-rendering process. In Next.js, when implementing child-to-parent routing, it's typical to showcase the parent component.**

```html
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import GlobalSearch from '@/app/Components/SharedComponents/GlobalSearch/page';
import UseTextField from '@/app/Components/SharedComponents/UseTextField/page';
import UseDropdown from '@/app/Components/SharedComponents/UseDropdown/page';
import UseButton from '@/app/Components/SharedComponents/UseButton/page';
import UseTable from '@/app/Components/SharedComponents/UseTable/page';
import { Card, CardContent, Grid, SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material';
import { BreadcrumbsNav } from '@/app/Components/SharedComponents/BreadCrumbsNav/page';
import { Search as SearchIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
import HeaderSideNav from '../../page';
import './Projects.css'
import Link from 'next/link';
import { getAccountsAPI, getIndustriesAPI, getPracticesAPI, getProjectsByUserRoleAPI } from '@/app/Components/Services/page';
import ComboBox from '@/app/Components/SharedComponents/AutoComplete/page';
import { withAuth } from '@/app/authGuard';


interface Option {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

interface Industry {
  industryId: string;
  name: string;
}
interface Project {
  projectId: string;
  clientName: string;
  industryType: string;
  practiceName: string;
  submittedBy: string;
  role: string;
  projectName: string;
  accountType: string;
  status: string;
  technology: string;
  description: string;
  architecture: string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
}

function Projects() {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);
  const [industriesData, setIndustriesData] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [selectedIndustry, setSelectedIndustry] = useState<string>('');
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);
  const [practise, setPractise] = useState([])
  const [account, setAccount] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const industriesData = await getIndustriesAPI();
        const namess = industriesData.map((industry: { name: any }) => industry.name);
        setNames(namess);
        const Practisedata = await getPracticesAPI();
        const practise = Practisedata.map((industry: { name: any }) => industry.name);
        setPractise(practise)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching industries data:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const Data = async () => {
      try {
        const acccdata = await getAccountsAPI();
        const accc = acccdata.map((industry: { accountType: any }) => industry.accountType);
        setAccount(accc)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching industries data:', error);
      }
    };
    Data();
  }, []);
  console.log();

  const [projects, setProjects] = useState<Project[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProjects();
  }, []);

  const fetchProjects = async () => {
    try {
      // Call getProjectsByUserRoleAPI function with the user role
      const projects = await getProjectsByUserRoleAPI('Project Manager');
  
      // Log the fetched projects
      console.log('Fetched projects:', projects);
      setProjects(projects)
    } catch (error) {
      // Log any errors that occur during the API call
      console.error('Error fetching projects:', error);
    }
  };
  const columns: TableColumn[] = [
    { label: 'Project ID', accessor: 'projectId' },
    { label: 'Client Name', accessor: 'clientName' },
    { label: 'Industry Type', accessor: 'industryType' },
    { label: 'Practice Name', accessor: 'practiceName' },
    { label: 'Submitted By', accessor: 'submittedBy' },
    { label: 'Status', accessor: 'status' },

  ];


  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = (query: string) => {
    console.log('Searching for:', query);
  };


  console.log(projects,"Projectss++++++++");
  
  const top100Films = [
    { label: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
    { label: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
    { label: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
    { label: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
    { label: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
    { label: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
    { label: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 },
    {
      label: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King',
      year: 2003,
    }]

  return (
    isMounted && (
      <HeaderSideNav>
        <BreadcrumbsNav
          links={[
            { name: "Home", to: "/Components/HeaderSideNav/Users/Projects" },
          ]}
          activeLink={"Projects"}
        />
        <br />
        <GlobalSearch onSearch={handleSearch} />
        <br />
        <Card sx={{ boxShadow: "none" }}>
          <CardContent>
            <Grid container rowSpacing={2} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
              <ComboBox options={top100Films} label={'Project Name'}  />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <UseDropdown
                  label={"Industry type"}
                  fullWidth
                  options={names}

                  onChange={(event) => setSelectedIndustry(event.target.value)} // Handle dropdown change
                  defaultValue={selectedIndustry}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <UseDropdown
                  label={"Account type"}
                  fullWidth
                  options={account}
                  onChange={(event) => console.log(event.target.value)} // Handle dropdown change
                  defaultValue={''}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <UseDropdown
                  label={"Practise"}
                  fullWidth options={practise} onChange={function (event: SelectChangeEvent<string>): void {
                    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
                  }} defaultValue={''} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <UseButton variant='contained' color="primary" fullWidth className="custom-button" >Reset</UseButton>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <UseButton variant='contained' color="primary" fullWidth style={{ height: "52px", backgroundColor: "#00aae7" }} >
                  <SearchIcon /> Search
                </UseButton>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
        {/* <br /> */}
        <UseTable columns={columns} data={projects} /> 
      </HeaderSideNav>
    )
  );
}

export default withAuth(Projects);
```

**I need to address the issue of unnecessary re-rendering of child components' pages, but we must halt this re-rendering process. In Next.js, when implementing child-to-parent routing, it's typical to showcase the parent component.**

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please share you code as a code snippet, add a simple example and explain what you tried and what is the expected behavior

Comment: I've included some code, could you please review it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like child components are re-rendering everytime a state change, you have multiple states (which is ok) but everytime each state is getting set (updated) it force all the children to re-render.

One thing you can do in order to avoid it is to depend the `isMounted` to be true only when you have all the state ready. till then you can show loading (or spinner).

for example:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if(names.length > 0 && practise.length > 0 && account.length > 0 && projects.length > 0){
    setIsMounted(true);
   }
  }, [names,practise,account,projects]);
```

This should make `isMouted` true only when the data is ready to be displayed, therefore it will prevent re-rendering anytime those states are updated.

in your return (jsx) you can show loader this way:

```
  isMounted ? (your JSX code...) : <div>Loading...</div>
```

or that way

```
!isMounted && <div>Loading...</div>
isMounted && (your JSX code...)
```

Potentialy you can think about adding loading state, so when you call `setSelectedIndustry` you can show a loader..